# Check if anything is in cin buffer

Tags: c++, string, input

I am writing a program that requires the user to enter some input via the console. Sometimes this will be one string, sometimes it will be two. I need to be able to check if one or two strings have been entered. What I am trying at the moment is this:

```
string s1,s2;
cin >> s1;

// do some operations on s1 (nothing using cout/cin)

if(thereIsASecondString()) {
    //do some operations on the second string
}
```

I am hoping there is some sort of function that I can use to see if a second string was entered. After searching I found things like `cin.eof()`, `cin.peek()` and `cin.rdbuf` but I either can't use them properly or they don't suit the purpose. Can someone tell me if there is a function that can achieve what I need (check if anything was entered after the first string)?

Alternatively, I could use getline() and then loop through that and split it into two strings where the space is (if there is one). Is this a better option? I would still like to know if it is possible to do with cin.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `istringstream` in combination with `getline`:

```
string line;
if (!getline(cin, line)) {
  // handle error...
}

istringstream iss(line);
string s1, s2;
if (!(iss >> s1)) {
  // we didn't even get one string, handle error...
}

// do something with s1

if (iss >> s2) {
  // there was a second string, do something with it
}
```